# How to change/jump to specific page in UIPageViewController

Tags: xcode, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I am trying to get my PageViewController to jump to a certain page (located at index 5 in my array) when a button is pressed. I have a button that calls changeToTimePage() which is located in my PageViewController class.

```
    func changeToTimePage() {
    print("This gets called")
    let startingViewController = viewControllerAtIndex(5)
    let viewControllers = [startingViewController]
    setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I can change pages just fine so I know viewControllerAtIndex works, but whenever I try to use setViewControllers() nothing happens. And I know the function is getting called because I see the output "This gets called". I've been looking for a solution for a very long time now and have tried many suggested methods so any help/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `setViewControllers...` is right. Here's a working project that might help you: https://github.com/mattneub/pageViewControllerUsingInternalButtons

Comment: Did you set your UIPageViewControllerDelegate?